# What is the difference between "increasingly less" and "decreasingly"?

Tags: difference, adverbs, negation, quantifiers

What is the difference between "increasingly less" and "decreasingly"?

Example:

- Selling X is getting *increasingly less* profitable.
- Selling X is getting *decreasingly* profitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken out of context, there is no difference.  "Decreasingly profitable" is an awkward turn of phrase, but it's not ungrammatical.

In an appropriate context -- say, a corporate announcement -- "increasingly less profitable" could be an example if not of actual [doublespeak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doublespeak) then at least of [sugarcoating](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sugarcoat) bad news.

If you say something is *decreasingly profitable* it's one word with a negative connotation ("decreasingly") paired with a similar-length word with a positive connotation ("profitable").  "Increasingly less profitable" is two long, positive words paired with one short, negative word.  It *sounds* more pleasant even though it *means* exactly the same thing.

Of course no one with half a brain is fooled by this -- but nevertheless this kind of verbiage is ubiquitous.

Answer (score 2):

> Selling X is getting increasingly less profitable

Indicates that **selling X** is still profitable, but less than it has been and **increasingly** means the rate at which it is becoming less profitable is going up.

> Selling X is getting decreasingly profitable

Only indicates that the profitability of selling X is going down.

Comment: This sounds like a distinction without a difference, sorry.

Comment: Not quite. "increasingly less" implies something that "decreasingly" doesn't. In the latter, profitable is modified by decreasingly whereas in the former, "increasingly" modifies "less" not "profitable" thus it is increasing in being less profitable (e.g. as when a price dives)

Comment: My point is that I don't think anyone will see that difference except in a strained, sophistic way.

Comment: I would theorize that either phrase would occur in technical writings where you might talk about derivatives (in the mathematical sense) thus rate of change for something like profitability might be discussed